# Calculate difference between values with nearly identical timestamp

Tags: r, data.table

Please consider these input data:

- I have two instruments (`41` and `54`).
- They both measure the pressure of several tanks (`T1` and `T2`).
- They measure the pressure nearly at the same time, but not exactly.

Example data:

```
data  <- data.table(
   time = as.POSIXct(paste("2017-01-01", c("11:59", "12:05", "12:02", "12:03", "14:00", "14:01", "14:02", "14:06")), tz = "GMT"),
   instrumentId = c(41, 54, 41, 54, 41, 54, 41, 54),
   tank = c("T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2"),
   pressure = c(25, 24, 35, 37.5, 22, 22.2, 38, 39.4))
```

I want to calculate the difference between the pressure measured by instrument 41 and by instrument 54, for each tank, assuming that values measured within 20 minutes belong to the same sample.

Ideall, the timestamp of the difference will be the mean of the timestamp of the two compared values.

Here is a script is use so far:

```
## Calculate difference of time between 2 consecutive lines
data <- data[, timeDiff := difftime(time, shift(time, type = "lag", fill = -Inf), tz = "GMT", units = "mins"),
                     by = tank]

# Assign the same timestamp to all the measures of a same sample
referenceTimes <- data[timeDiff > 20, .(time)]
data <- data[timeDiff < 20, time := referenceTimes]

# Calculate the difference between the values measured by both instruments
wideDt <- dcast.data.table(data,time + tank ~ instrumentId, value.var = c( "pressure"))
instruments <- as.character(unique(data$instrumentId))
wideDt <- wideDt[, difference := get(instruments[1]) - get(instruments[2])]
```

It does the job, but its biggest problem is that the data should be sorted the proper way, otherwise time shift calculation returns nonsense.
With the example input data it is OK, but try to "unsort" them with `data <- data[order(pressure)]` for example. In that case, `data <- data[order(tank, time, instrumentId)]` should be added.

Moreover, I have the impression that it could be more concise, more efficient, and cleaner. In a word, it could better use `data.table`'s strength.

Expected result is:

```
time                 tank  41   54    difference
-------------------------------------------------
2017-01-01 11:59:00  T1    25   24.0   1.0
2017-01-01 12:02:00  T2    35   37.5  -2.5
2017-01-01 14:00:00  T1    22   22.2  -0.2
2017-01-01 14:02:00  T2    38   39.4  -1.4
```

Any idea how to perform this task properly?

Comment: You could group each "time" on a group of 20-minute intervals (`findInterval(data$time, seq(data$time[1], data$time[nrow(data)], by = "20 mins"))`) and apply `diff(pressure)` grouping by that interval & "tank"

Comment: @Cath If you are not okay with that dupe, don't tag it.  I also didn't tag it as dupe as I am not 100% sure.

Comment: @Cath Even the OP had named his object as `wideDt`.

Comment: @docendodiscimus  Now, I understand it is not a dupe.  I will delete that link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily perform a rolling self-join on two subsets on both `tank` and `time` which won't require any initial reordering while specifying the maximum rolling interval (20 mins = 20 * 60 secs)

```
res <- 
 data[instrumentId == 54, .SD[data[instrumentId == 41], on = .(tank, time), roll = -20*60]]
res
#                   time instrumentId tank pressure i.instrumentId i.pressure
# 1: 2017-01-01 11:59:00           54   T1     24.0             41         25
# 2: 2017-01-01 12:02:00           54   T2     37.5             41         35
# 3: 2017-01-01 14:00:00           54   T1     22.2             41         22
# 4: 2017-01-01 14:02:00           54   T2     39.4             41         38
```

Then, calculating the difference is just a matter of `res[, difference := pressure - i.pressure]`

But if you want your exact desired format, I'm afraid it will require some melting/dcasting

```
res2 <-
  dcast(
    melt(res, c("time", "tank"), 
         measure = patterns("instrumentId", "pressure")),
    time + tank ~ value1, value.var = "value2"
        )[, difference := `41` - `54`]

res2
#                   time tank 41   54 difference
# 1: 2017-01-01 11:59:00   T1 25 24.0        1.0
# 2: 2017-01-01 12:02:00   T2 35 37.5       -2.5
# 3: 2017-01-01 14:00:00   T1 22 22.2       -0.2
# 4: 2017-01-01 14:02:00   T2 38 39.4       -1.4
```

Comment: Thanks. `roll` was the feature I wasn't aware of.